# msbuild Target element - what if a file in Inputs does not exist

Tags: msbuild

[Target Element (MSBuild)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx)

***Inputs***: Optional attribute.
The files that form inputs into this target. Multiple files are separated by semicolons. The timestamps of the files will be compared with the timestamps of files in Outputs to determine whether the Target is up to date. For more information, see Incremental Builds, How to: Build Incrementally, and Transforms.

**QUESTION**
What happens if there's a file that's in `Inputs` that doesn't actually exist?
Will the target be considered **out-of-date**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current beavhior is that incremental targets are built when inputs are missing. That is, the target will be considered out-of date when a file in the inputs list cannot be found.

This behavior is implemented in [`TargetUpToDateChecker`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/97d694f3784300852b36d61c5a79dcedca9c51f2/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetUpToDateChecker.cs) and produces log messages like:

```
Building target "Build" completely.
Input file "input1.txt" does not exist.
```

Note that while missing files cause rebuilds, changing the files of input elements doesn't matter - e.g. when the first build has `Inputs="a.txt;b.txt"` and the second build has `Input="a.txt"`, the target is still up-to-date. This can happen in situations where the input list is filled by items created using patterns (e.g. `<Foo Include="*.txt" />` items and `Input="@(Foo)"`).